# I can't Segue using a UIButton from UIViewController to UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I'm getting Thread 1 SIGABRT in my AppDelegate class with the following

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier
>   "UIViewController-ynt-fo-t3z" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a
>   UITableView.'

Storyboard arrangement:

UIViewController --> UITableViewController

I'm using a menu Button item from UIViewcontroller to trigger the segue.  I have tried everything including preparedforSegue method.  The only way around is to change the target view controller back to UIViewController while implementing UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource which I'm not too fond of using.  Any solutions to my madness?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue long time ago; I tried anything, and nothing worked. I ended up using a new UITableViewController and segueing to it; And the issue was resolved. (it seemed like a bug in Xcode or something)

Do the same and see if it works for you.